# Issue with Google Maps JavaScript API V3 in <details>-tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a issue implementing Google Maps JavaScript API V3 in a `<details>`-tag. I run `initialize();` when clicking the `<summary>`-tag. The first time the map displays correctly but if I close the `<details>`-tag and open it again it doesn't display correctly.

**The issue**

[image: Google Maps API]

**HTML**

```
<details id="address">

    <summary onclick="initialize();">My map</summary>

    <div id="maps" class="box box_addon">

        <div id="map_canvas1"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas2"></div>

    </div>

</details>
```

**Javascript**

```
function initialize() {

    var isOpen = ($('#address').attr('open') == 'open');

    if(!isOpen){

        var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>);

        var mapOptions;
        var map;
        var marker;

        // Karta 1

        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: centerPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false

        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas1'), mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: centerPosition
        });

        // Karta 2

        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: centerPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: centerPosition
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: You can try to resize or refresh the map

Comment: Tried resizing but it didn't work. How do you refresh the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try triggering the resize event for the map after you open it again.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

From the documentation

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .

Comment: Tried to put it under `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas1'), mapOptions);` but it didn't change.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're creating the map over and over again.  Why not just show/hide the div and only recreate the map if map is undefined?

Comment: Good point, added `if(map == undefined){`. Also placed the code after the details tag and it's now working!